# is there any linkedIn API which returns current job openings in a certin company?

Tags: linkedin-api

a couple of months ago I made this https://github.com/Kaustubh-Natuskar/companies-to-apply  repository which contains the list of 300 PBC's and startups I got a good response for that. But I have decided to take this further I want to make a website from this idea.

1. there will be a list of companies if there is an opening a red circle will denote it.
   Now the problem is how can I know that there are openings?
   API is a great option where I can cache the results and then display them like above.
   is there any API on LinkedIn where if I post a request with the company's id or name I'll get current openings?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it.

There is the [Job Posts XML feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/job-postings/xml-feeds), but the documentation implies that it's not free (and difficult to get access to):

> - The integration of the XML feed is limited to those developers approved by LinkedIn. Reach out to your Business Development contact to meet certain criteria and sign an agreement in order to use this integration.
> - Compliance with our contract and guidelines is integral. Refer to Job Posting Guidelines for details.
> - If you are not yet a LinkedIn Talent Solutions Partner, please contact the team at ll-bd@linkedin.com to request for evaluation.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/) is Microsoft's full documentation on the LinkedIn APIs.